# Return object in javascript array with lowest value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of cities that contain a key "distance"

```
ajax = new Location('123 main street', 'city, ON', 'L9Z 0K5', '905-555-5555', '905-555-555', 43.864362, -79.011627, 6);
alliston = new Location('117 Young Street', 'place, ON', 'L5R 0E9', '705-555-1234', '705-444-4321', 44.147691, -79.884193, 15);
aurora = new Location('2 New Place', 'capitol, ON', 'L8G 3W8', '905-999-0155', '905-727-5678', 44.009139, -79.470980, 1);
brampton = new Location('50 Circle Cres.', 'wendy, ON', 'L9r 8S1', '905-888-8888', null, 43.680537, -79.714164, 25);
```

These objects (where the last key is distance) are stored in an array called cities

How can I loop through cities and print the object that contains the lowest distance?

Answer (score 2):

```
cities.reduce(function(a, b) {
 return (b.distance < a.distance)  ? b : a;
})
```

||

```
cities.sort(function(a, b) {
 return a.distance - b.distance;
})[0]
```

Comment: -1: The first one doesn't work; I tried it.  It's using `Array.reduce` incorrectly.

Comment: @EthanBrown Care to explain? For what input does it fail?

Comment: Nope.  I don't think you're getting how `Array.reduce` works.  If you pass in `Number.MIN_VALUE` as a seed, the test will always fail (because `Number.MIN_VALUE` does not have a property `distance`, so you will always have (some number) < undefined, which will always return false).  See my answer below using reduce, which works, and has been tested.

Comment: This is the array I've been testing against: `[{distance:5},{distance:7},{distance:2}]`.  Your current incarnation, it returns `5e-324` (aka `Number.MIN_VALUE`).  For your previous one, it returned `{distance:5}`.

Comment: Uh-oh, I knew that, just... but thank you nonetheless for making me to actually look up the docs. But won't undefined coerce to 0 in the expression, so it wouldn't matter? Scratch that, I don't know where my mind is right now.

Comment: I can't remember exactly how coercion works with inequality operators, but it isn't coercing to 0 (more likely, the number is coercing to a string).  I know this because if you do `-3 < undefined`, you get `false`.  If `undefined` were coercing to 0, that would yield `true`.

Comment: @EthanBrown Thank you, you were patient with me and I appreciate it. You deserve an upvote. Please do tell if there's something wrong now?

Comment: +1 Looks like you finally got it!  A little neater than my answer to boot...I ended up learning a little bit about `reduce` my own self (I was not aware of its default behavior if you don't supply an initial value...that's handy to know).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` method of `Array` (I'm assuming here your `Location` object has a property called `distance`; adjust accordingly):

```
var nearest = [ajax,alliston,aurora,brampton]
    .reduce( function( nearest, location ) { 
        return !nearest || location.distance < nearest.distance 
            ? location : nearest;
    } );
```

Note: iccthedral's solution using `reduce` is a little neater than mine, thanks to his clever use of `reduce`'s behavior if you don't supply an initial value.  From MDN: "If no initialValue was provided, then [the first argument passed to the callback] will be equal to the first value in the array."

Answer (score 0):

Put them into an object/array and create custom sort function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

...which will sort this array by distance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use arrayObject.sort(sortby); and define your sortby function (e.g., return loc_a.distance - loc_b.distance).